# How to check if someone shared my page's post? Using Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I have the read_stream access from user, I want to award him some points if he shares one of my pages' post. Now I have Claim Point button so I can crawl his posts, and I want to check if he has shared my page's post (using Share link of Facebook, near Comment and Like ). I had an Idea, if someone shares others' post it appears as a link, so I tried to match the link with my page's link, but if its a Facebook link (or post like status, note) then `url` form below FQL returns `null`. Same happens with Graph API (link doesn't appear).

```
select url,link_id,title from link where owner=me()
```

It works fine if its an external link (which is not helpful for me).

So what's the problem here? And I am **open to other ideas**, to check if user has shared my post.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution. Normal calls don't return Shared Posts' links at all. But Feed returns, so crawling feed makes my task done.

> https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed/?access_token=your_access_token

Answer (score 1):

Nice way but will only work in Graph API 1.0

Some test in the Graph explorer looks quite clean

```
https:/graph.facebook.com/me/feed/?fields=link,story,status_type&limit=100&status_type=shared_story
```

Now parse the link if it contains the Page ID or your domain . If the last 100 post have more than one share from the page he get ranked up or some Superpoints .

Thank you Usman for the hint in the right direction

Comment: Is it possible to get the ID of the original post, if I have the ID of the post that shared the original post?