# Facebook API: Get Shared Post ID

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Using FB Graph API, is it possible to check if the post is shared like this one? https://www.facebook.com/alexey.kosov/posts/10203624447732200

And how to get the original post id?

Comment: Any progress with your question? I'm also have the ID of the post that includes the shared / original post, and I need to know an answer to your question + how to get the shared / original post ID.

Comment: Did you check out this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674677/how-to-check-if-someone-shared-my-pages-post-using-facebook-api

Answer (score 5):

In your URL https://www.facebook.com/alexey.kosov/posts/10203624447732200  the 10203624447732200 is your public post id. With the API **v2.0** you can get the shared posts with the edge `sharedposts`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/object/sharedposts

According to the documentation on v2.0:

> For page posts, public posts by the page are retrievable with any valid access token. Posts by people on the page, posts by people which mention the page, or targeted page posts (by language or geography, for example) may require a user or page token.
>   A user access token with `read_stream` or `user_posts permission` for any other posts

So you need a token with one of the two permissions.

I tried to retrieve the share from your post: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=10203624447732200%2Fsharedposts&version=v2.0

And it returned me `{"data": []}`, however after I shared the post, I repeated the call and I was able to see the post that I just shared in the results.

Now, if I use the `post_id` that I just shared, I receive again an empty result. So you can see only see who shared the post but not if it was shared from somebody else.
If you think of shared posts as nodes of a tree, you can only see what happens on the subtree under the node with the `post_id` that you have.

You also need to consider that you will not be able to retrieve the re-shared posts that are not visible to you. i.e.: if I share your post with privacy "Only me" or if I share it with privacy "Friends" and we are not friends you will not be able to see it.

Comment: Thank you, I confirmed what you said with test, but still:

Q1: how can I tell if the link that I have is a link of the original post or a link to a shared post?

2- If there's no direct way to solve Q1, I can fetch the received error (Singular requests are depreciated .... ), which will mostly indicates that it's a shared post link, but how can I get the original post ID from the shared post link or shared post ID (And I have both of them).

Comment: I hope you may have more tips to share about this question, thank you :)

Comment: You get `(#12) singular statuses API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher` if you are using v2.4 or v.2.5 of the API. If you use v2.0 to v.2.3 it will not give you that message. You can walk the tree of shared article only top-down. You can only verify that the post is shared from another post if you have the parent but as far as I know there is no way to find the parent from the child.

Comment: The best I was able to do is to run a search in FB UI for the title of the post: https://www.facebook.com/search/top/?q=FbStart%20distributes%20%24100%20million%20in%20benefits%20to%20more%20than%203%2C800%20startups%20in%20the%20first%20year that returned me a post from Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/FacebookforDevelopers/posts/10152897601858553 Now, if you run an API call for that post on the sharedposts edge https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=10152897601858553%2Fsharedposts&version=v2.3 you will find all the shared posts with privacy tule that include you

Comment: So you may be able to walk down each post and eventually find the post that you are looking for. However you cannot do anything if one of the node between the original post and the one that you want to verify was shared from that is not visible to you. Ex: Alexey shared the post from one of his friend that shared the post with just his friends and you are not friend with this Alexey's friend, you will not be able to establish that Alexey shared the post from his friend and who this friend is.

Comment: Anyway, it is pretty complicated. Can I ask you what is your use case?  What are you trying to find out?  What are you going to do if you had the original post and who posted it?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining my usage, knowing that indeed I use API 2.5

1st: The visibility of the original post or the post that shared the original post are not a problem, as their links will be copied by the user of my app and deliver it to my app that he already logged in with and granted it required permission. 

2nd: Usage: If the original post has a video, & the user of my app used the URL of a post shared the original post, I can't fetch the video's details & I receive the error mentioned above (#12 singular.), So I need the original post ID to fetch video's details via GraphRequest.

Comment: This is a url of an original post on Thor movie page, share it on your wall, copy your post url, and now try to fetch the video's details, you will get the error #12 singular ... https://www.facebook.com/Thor/videos/921802087855994/

Comment: @ Astrount: So how does your app get the post_id? What does the app  user  do so the app receive the post id ? Is it a post that the user has already shared ?

Depending what you are doing there are 2 solutions: (1) use API v.2.3 to get the details in the post - you can try to prepend `/v.2.3/` to the post id in your call to `GraphRequest` (2) make sure that you get the full post id from the API, the one that has the format: `usedId_postId`

Comment: I extract the post ID (Who shared the original post) from the URL provided by the user, and user gets the URL by opening the post options menu and select (Copy post link) ... All this of course via the Facebook application for Android.

Comment: @AshrafAlshahawy did you find a way to fetch the original post id from the shared one? Please tell me if you've succeeded doing this.

Comment: @HamzehSoboh For sorry I couldn't, and the Facebook group for Facebook developer wasn't helpful to find an answer.

Comment: Hi, If any one get the answer for v2.4 and higher versions, please provide the code. It will be very helpfull to me.