# how to get the facebook post details from share url in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook share url like this (https://www.facebook.com/pus18/videos/498575787191356/). From the share url i want to get details like post id, title, source, length of the video. Please give suggestions if possible please provide the code to get the details of the post in iOS.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to take a look at Facebook guide that is connected with [posts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/post).

From this guide it is easy to get information that you are searching for.

Objective-c style.

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                               initWithGraphPath:@"/{post-id}"
                                      parameters:params
                                      HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                      id result,
                                      NSError *error) {


}];
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. How to use the url to get the post id.

Comment: @Ajay in case you show you're video id will be 498575787191356

Comment: Ok. please give the suggestions for this type of urls 

https://www.facebook.com/shreyaghoshal/posts/10155774118036484

Comment: @Ajay 1553667851356569

Comment: Please share the code to get solution. I kept the code like this.

Comment: @Ajay take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33038398/facebook-api-get-shared-post-id

Comment: NSString*idstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/",postID];
                         FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                                       initWithGraphPath:idstr
                                                       parameters:postparams
                                                       HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
it shows the error like this"(#12) singular statuses API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher"

Comment: I give the user_posts permission and i used the above code same error is (#12) singular statuses API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher. And also implemented the "postid/sharedposts"  . same error is getting. please give suggestions to get the response for "posts/postid" typer urls

Comment: I want to get the video details from the post in this type of url facebook.com/shreyaghoshal/posts/10155774118036484 . I get this link from the Facebook app in iOS device. Except this copied link and Facebook login user details i don't have any details about this url . Facebook version is above the 2.4 version. I used the code graph request to get the details like "/{postid}" it shows the (#12) singular statuses API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher. Please give suggestions and code to solve this issue.